# How do I save the user instance instead of a user string in this example?

Tags: django, django-views

I made a form to review the user whose profile you're viewing.  I am trying to pass the username (named test here) from the URL directly into the view.  I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError at /reviewseller/Benino/
Cannot assign "u'Benino'": "UserReview.name" must be a "User" instance.
```

Models.py

```
class UserReview(models.Model):
    name= models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='usersbeingreviewed', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='reviewauthors')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    stars = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.name, self.author, self.pub_date, self.stars, self.comment)
```

URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r"^reviewseller/(?P<test>\w+)/$", get_review))
```

Views.Py

```
def get_review(request, test):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p = UserReviewForm(request.POST)
        if p.is_valid():
            reviewform=p.save(commit=False)
            reviewform.name=test
            reviewform.author=request.user
            reviewform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

Do I need to add something in the view to filter through all existing instances by username?  Or something like that?  How do I convert the string into the user instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're doing in the view inside the is_valid clause: test is not defined.

The easiest thing to do here is to define a `clean_name` on the form, which looks up the use by name and returns it:

```
def clean_name(self):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['name'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Enter a valid name")
    return user
```